# <md-icon> icon formats used to create the md-icon other than svg

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In Angular Materials md-icon attribute md-svr-src , is there any other format other than svg available for

i have tired to include the ico format to create the angular material icon ..is there any way to create the  using the .ico format and .png format

Answer (score 0):

The md-icon directive makes it easier to use vector-based icons in your app (as opposed to raster-based icons types like PNG). The directive supports both icon fonts and SVG icons :

```
 <md-button class="md-icon-button">
  <img class="yourClass" src="path/to/your/image.png">
</md-button>
```